# Convert local time and timezone to UTC?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I have got multiple timezones and datetimes and I want to convert these to UTC timezone using python. For Example:

**Timezone** **Datetime**
GMT+5 10-03-2019 01:00:00
EST 10-03-2019 01:00:00
CET 10-03-2019 01:00:00

Answer should be:

UTC 09-03-2019 20:00:00
UTC 10-03-2019 05:00:00
UTC 10-03-2019 02:00:00

Comment: Is that the exact format of your data?

Comment: Yes. This is the format we are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't bring parsing the timezone to work with the builtin datetime, but using the `arrow` module worked. I'm assuming your dates are in DD/MM/YYYY and not MM/DD/YYYY.

```
import arrow

def parse_date(string):
    mydate = arrow.get(string, "ZZZ DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:SS")
    return mydate.to("utc").strftime("%Z %d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")

parse_date("GMT+5 10-03-2019 01:00:00")
parse_date("EST 10-03-2019 01:00:00")
parse_date("CET 10-03-2019 01:00:00")
```

Output:

```
'UTC 09-03-2019 20:00:00'
'UTC 10-03-2019 06:00:00'
'UTC 10-03-2019 00:00:00'
```

`arrow` documentation on format tokens can be found [here](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#tokens).